# Is Canoncialize package breaking oAuth in my mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, routes, canonicalization

I've been using Schourode's Canoncialize package to ensure all urls are lowercase. I find it really convenient and would like to continue using it.

https://github.com/schourode/canonicalize

But I hit a snag when using OAuthWebSecurity. The AuthorizationResult was failing. Removing the call to Canonicalize in route_config.cs made it work again.

I had originally thought it was rewriting to the request token to lowercase, but as Chandu pointed out I was mistaken.  Now I'm thinking it might be encoding related. But I'm not sure why exactly it's happening or how to approach fixing it. :(

**Successful Callback URL**

```
http://localhost:54829/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=google
& __sid__=fcb698f12ed04960927d4ac90e56e61e
& dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid
& openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
& openid.mode=id_res
& openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud
& openid.response_nonce=2013-09-14T14%3A27%3A18Z6FEiPEQHHaoPbA
& openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54829%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3Dgoogle%26__sid__%3Dfcb698f12ed04960927d4ac90e56e61e%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid
& openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9UwBb4zH8OdmM32r_inWmnlZxOI5YYiDIyvZyYzWHSDOhrSr4BXyqr_o5hN
& openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.alias1%2Cext1.value.alias1
& openid.sig=hnrnpAd6y%2FnNsZ%2F%2F%2FUxwF5y3fdQ%3D
& openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnOx9rmVJrEUZJ_Kw7O513sw1IE4I7kBhE
& openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawnOx9rmVJrEUZJ_Kw7O513sw1IE4I7kBhE
& openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0
& openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response
& openid.ext1.type.alias1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail
& openid.ext1.value.alias1=myemail%40gmail.com
```

**Failed Callback URL**

```
http://localhost:54829/account/externallogincallback?__provider__=google
& __sid__=49c61b3f66404ec0bedfa36764d462cc
& dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
& openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
& openid.mode=id_res
& openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
& openid.response_nonce=2013-09-14T14:25:49ZRLQRLeenDyhw3A
& openid.return_to=http://localhost:54829/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=google
& __sid__=49c61b3f66404ec0bedfa36764d462cc
& dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid
& openid.assoc_handle=1.AMlYA9WrOftO7I7kuyIEwBrDNP-7SXGCRijUDbHG_7yNd_SuasIglPfyLWegbAD6
& openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,ns.ext1,ext1.mode,ext1.type.alias1,ext1.value.alias1
& openid.sig=SMD+cRIfP3E3Y9lZ29tBFBmg2uE=
& openid.identity=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnOx9rmVJrEUZJ_Kw7O513sw1IE4I7kBhE
& openid.claimed_id=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawnOx9rmVJrEUZJ_Kw7O513sw1IE4I7kBhE
& openid.ns.ext1=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
& openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response
& openid.ext1.type.alias1=http://axschema.org/contact/email
& openid.ext1.value.alias1=myemail@gmail.com
```

**Here's the call that makes or breaks it:**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        // removing this causes oAuth to work ok
        routes.Canonicalize().NoWww().Lowercase().NoTrailingSlash();

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: From what /i see LowercaseStrategy is just changing the url path and not the query string. Can you confirm if its canoicalize thats converting the querystring values to lowercase indeed? Or better yet if you can provide a simple setup to replicate the issue that would be helpful.

Comment: You're totally correct, I saw the first section of the auth token and jumped to the wrong conclusion.  I'm going to update the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Related: http://www.eisenhartsoftware.com/blog/post/OAuth-and-Canonical-Site-URLs-The-Order-Matters